# Error when uploading images using Play! Framework on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, playframework, upload

I'm using Play! Framework and i'm having troubles to make upload of images, especially in Google Chrome:

```
[error] play - Exception caught in RequestBodyHandler
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:433)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:128)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779
```

On client-side, this is the request code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.images.length; i++) {
  formData.append('picture' + i, $scope.images[i]);
}

$http.post('/resource/ad/' + id + '/upload', formData, {
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
});
```

On server, it's like that:

```
play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
List<Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
```

I changed the values of my parameters in application.conf:

```
parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength=50240K
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=50240K
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=50240K
```

The funny thing is that just happens in Chrome. In Firefox, for example, it's working.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I had something similar with Chrome. The Chrome's file browser doesn't let you choose the same file twice. The second time it just gives nothing back although I choose the same file again. Try uploading a different file or do a reload of your page.

Comment: @Kris still could not solve this way. I've done several studies and found no answer. Can you help me or know someone who dominates the Play? I don't know why Chrome reacts that way.